# How do I generate a project template within code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core Web API. One of my scenarios looks like this: the user selects a certain project type/language. Lets say the user selects Python or C#, meaning the user wants to create a Python or C# project template. Is it possible/is there an easy way to create such a project template within the code or would I have to create all files manually in the code? This is actually simply simulating the scenario when a user wants to create a new project in Visual Studio where he selects a template from the create a new project menu, its just that I want to do this with my own service.

Answer (score 1):

For .NET: I would make use of the `dotnet new` cli tool, and use the `ProcessStartInfo` together with the `Process.Start`.

For Python, I would do the same, but require the intallation of `pyscaffold`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an embedded resource which is e.g. a ZIP file that contains all the files you need to make a project. You can then extract the ZIP file in your code. That way you can simply update the ZIP file in case you want to add something or update to a newer version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand or maybe I couldn't explain my problem fully. So from my point of view nothing exists initially, there are no project files whatsoever. The user uses the API and selects Python for example. I want to generate the template/project files from zero, which I will send to the users repository of choice in the second phase.

Comment: Yes, so clone the empty repository, unzip the embedded resource, `git add`, `git commit`, `git push` and the project files are in the repo.